# Rails update_all for each array element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a follow method, it works well

```
def update 
  ids = params["_json"].map { |hash| hash["id"] }  # --> return [10, 20, 30, 40 ] 
  positions = params["_json"].map { |hash| hash["position"] } # --> return [0, 1, 2, 3 ] 
  
  query = MyQueryQuery.new
  query.visible = true
  query.active = true
  
  available = query.fetch.map(&:id)
      ::Model.where(id: (ids & available))
        .update_all(show_home: true, updated_at: DateTime.now)
end
```

How can I change this method to update a new column in my Model called position with each element from postions array? For example, in Model(id: 10, position: 0), Model(id: 20, position: 1), Model(id: 30, position: 2) etc ....

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the .map from positions and get the elements from hash to update, like that.

```
positions = params["_json"]
 
positions.each do |p| 
  model = Model.find(p['id'])
  model.update(position: p['position'])
end
```